# Error sonarqube scanner:Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: .net, docker, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Hello community friends

Currently I'm trying to use sonarqube(v9.6.1) to scan my dotnet(v6.0) project but in the process I receive the error below and I don't know why? the output is not very clear.

On the sonarqube community I check a related [issue](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-path-line-0-position-0/46033), but is not my case because I'm using the latest docker image of sonar

I'll really appreciate any hint can guide me to solve the issue.

Regards

```bash
dotnet sonarscanner begin \
    /k:"test" \
    /d:sonar.host.url="https://sqserver.com" \
    /d:sonar.login="**************************" \
    /d:sonar.verbose=true> > > > 
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.8
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Default properties file was found at /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/5.8.0/dotnet-sonarscanner/5.8.0/tools/netcoreapp3.0/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/5.8.0/dotnet-sonarscanner/5.8.0/tools/netcoreapp3.0/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
14:14:35.726  14:14:35.716  Loading analysis properties from /root/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-sonarscanner/5.8.0/dotnet-sonarscanner/5.8.0/tools/netcoreapp3.0/any/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
14:14:35.727  14:14:35.726  sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
14:14:35.731  Updating build integration targets...
14:14:35.737  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.739  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/10.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.74  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/11.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.742  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/12.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.743  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/14.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.745  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/15.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.774  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/.local/share/Microsoft/MSBuild/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.775  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/Microsoft/MSBuild/15.0/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.776  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to /root/Microsoft/MSBuild/Current/Microsoft.Common.targets/ImportBefore
14:14:35.778  Installed SonarQube.Integration.targets to /app/.sonarqube/bin/targets
14:14:35.78  Creating config and output folders...
14:14:35.782  Creating directory: /app/.sonarqube/conf
14:14:35.784  Creating directory: /app/.sonarqube/out
14:14:35.805  Downloading from https://sqserver.com/api/server/version...
14:14:36.026  Checking validity of server license
14:14:36.028  Downloading from https://sqserver.com/api/editions/is_valid_license...
14:14:36.051  Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
14:14:36.054  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: Does the response of https://sqserver.com/api/editions/is_valid_license look okay?

Comment: that api call return the following error
404 Unknown Reason The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: So this seems to be your real problem, a not fully functional Sonar server

Comment: yep, that's the real problem, looking on the internet there are others who have the same issue, but it's not clear how to solve it. On the api(sqserver.com/web_api) section I didn't see the license route api(api/editions/is_valid_license ).I don't know if I have to enable it somewhere or not.
The sonarqube are used with others types of projects and it works properly.